# The track package button doesn't show up

Tags: google-schemas

I add the body html and script. I test my email and i don't see the track package button in gmail. I follow the code from this page. I add my script in my body, before the table tag. Is there anything I'm missing? I use the aptos token for dynamic content.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/parcel-delivery

```js
var today = new Date();
var today_date = today.toISOString();
var days = 7;
var res = today.setTime(today.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
date7 = new Date(res);
var dt = new Date(date7);
var date_after_seven_days = dt.toISOString();
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.type = 'application/ld+json';
el.text = JSON.stringify(
    {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ParcelDelivery",
  "deliveryAddress": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "name": "[SHIPNAME]",
    "streetAddress": "[SHIPSTREET]",
    "addressLocality": "[SHIPCITY]",
    "addressRegion": "[SHIPSTATE]",
    "addressCountry": "[SHIPCOUNTRY]",
    "postalCode": "[SHIPZIP]"
  },
  "originAddress": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "name": "[BILLNAME]",
    "streetAddress": "[BILLSTREET]",
    "addressLocality": "[BILLCITY]",
    "addressRegion": "[BILLSTATE]",
    "addressCountry": "[BILLCOUNTRY]",
    "postalCode": "[BILLZIP]"
  },
  "expectedArrivalFrom": today_date,
  "expectedArrivalUntil": date_after_seven_days,
  "carrier": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "UPS",
    "url": "http://kicksusa.wesupply.xyz"
  },
  "itemShipped": {
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "[PROD NAME]",
    "sku": "[PROD SKU]"
    }
  },
  "trackingNumber": "[ORDER_TRACKINGNUMBER]",
  "trackingUrl": "http://kicksusa.wesupply.xyz/track/[ORDER_TRACKINGNUMBER]",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "TrackAction",
    "target": "http://kicksusa.wesupply.xyz/track/[ORDER_TRACKINGNUMBER]"
  },
  "hasDeliveryMethod": "http://schema.org/ParcelService",
  "partOfOrder": {
    "@type": "Order",
    "orderNumber": "[ORDERNUMBER]",
    "merchant": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "[BILLNAME]",
      "sameAs": "http://www.freebase.com/m/0fhkx"
    },
    "orderStatus": "http://schema.org/OrderInTransit"
  }
}
);
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(el);
```

```html
<!-- Email body : BEGIN -->
            <table style="background-color: #ffffff; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; max-width: 600px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="max-width: 600px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; border-color: #ccc;" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <!--start intro table -->
                                    <table style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <!-- Spacer : BEGIN -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="30" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <!-- Spacer : END -->

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style="margin: auto;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px">
                                                                <p>Dear [BILLNAME],<br><br>Your order is on its way! Please see your order tracking information below:</p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <!-- Spacer : BEGIN -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="20" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <!-- Spacer : END -->

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table style="max-width: 350px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; border-color: #ccc;" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                                                        <tr valign="middle">
                                                            <td style="border-top: 1px solid #F6F6F6; border-left: 1px solid #F6F6F6; border-right: 1px solid #F6F6F6;">
                                                                <table style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="14">
                                                                    
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; line-height: 20px;" width="50%">Order Number:</td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;" width="50%">#[EXTERNALORDERID]</td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr valign="middle">
                                                            <td style="border-top: 1px solid #F6F6F6; border-left: 1px solid #F6F6F6; border-right: 1px solid #F6F6F6;">
                                                                <table style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="14">
                                                                    
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; line-height: 20px;" width="50%">Order Shipped:</td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;" width="50%">[ORDER_SHIPPINGDATE]</td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr valign="middle">
                                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #F6F6F6; border-top: 1px solid #F6F6F6; border-left: 1px solid #F6F6F6; border-right: 1px solid #F6F6F6;">
                                                                <table style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="14">
                                                                    
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; line-height: 20px;" width="50%">Tracking Number:</td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;" width="50%"><a href="http://kicksusa.wesupply.xyz/track/[ORDER_TRACKINGNUMBER]">[ORDER_TRACKINGNUMBER]</a></td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                     
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            
                                            <!-- Spacer : BEGIN -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="20" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <!-- Spacer : END -->

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style="margin: auto;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px">
                                                                <p>If you have any concerns or questions, please contact our Customer Service Team at 1-844-477-6402 or <a href="mailto:support@kicksusa.zendesk.com">support@kicksusa.zendesk.com</a>.</p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <!-- Spacer : BEGIN -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="20" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <!-- Spacer : END -->
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end intro table -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
          
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Spacer : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="50" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Spacer : END -->
                

            </table>
            <!-- Email Body : END -->
```

Comment: Your code have a syntax error when we run the snippet

Comment: Your brackets "{ }" are unbalanced in you JSON object

Comment: which part? can u show me?

Comment: Just above `"trackingNumber": "[ORDER_TRACKINGNUMBER]",`

Comment: do you mean this one?   "itemShipped": {
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "[PROD NAME]",
    "sku": "[PROD SKU]"
    }
  }, 
i have to remove of these "}"?

Comment: Yes, you have to remove the last one

Comment: Ok i remove the last one and test the email again. The track package button is not showing up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151532/discussion-between-waisie-li-and-litelite).